# Concating a nested numpy array into 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas, scikit-learn

I am using Pandas to generate some information and features. I will be using that database as my input for sklearn. Currently, I am converting the dataframe to array using `.as_matrix()`. Following is the output:

```
array([[0.4437294900417328, 0.13434134423732758, 0.474, 0.482,
    array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0])],
   [0.09896088391542435, 0.10105254501104355, 0.474, 0.526,
    array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0])],
   [0.026971107348799706, 0.08766224980354309, 0.474, 0.581,
    array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0])],
   ...,
```

I want to dissolve this inner array into the parent 2D array. The result should look something like this.

```
array([[0.4437294900417328, 0.13434134423732758, 0.474, 0.482,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
   [0.09896088391542435, 0.10105254501104355, 0.474, 0.526,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0.026971107348799706, 0.08766224980354309, 0.474, 0.581,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
   ...,
```

TIA

Comment: it ought to be outputting a 2d array already unless something is weird about your data.  what does you dataframe look like before the `as_matrix()`?

Comment: The outer array is dtype object.  If the subarrays had the same size, ravel followed by concatenate might work.

Comment: You need to tell us the `shape` and `dtype` of the main array.  There are several levels of nesting that is hard to decipher from the print out.  Is it an array of lists or a 2d array?  It looks like the inner list or dimension consists of a bunch of floats plus an array.  We need to know this to be able recreate the array (not the exact numbers, just the structure) and play with it in an interactive shell.

Comment: I was adding appending `array` in my `dataframe`. That was leading to this weird looking data. I resolved my problem by not doing that. Later i found out about `np.c_` that was the answer i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, the exact structure of your array is unclear.  I'm sure the outer dtype is object.  Pandas often uses that to hold mixed data.

Here's a guess, and possible solution:

Make an object array and fill it with some floats and arrays of integers:

```
In [38]: A=np.empty((3,5),dtype=object)
In [39]: A[:,:4]=np.arange(12.).reshape(3,4)/10
In [40]: A[0,-1]=np.arange(5)
In [41]: A[1,-1]=np.arange(1,6)
In [42]: A[2,-1]=np.arange(2,7)
In [43]: A
Out[43]: 
array([[0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])],
       [0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])],
       [0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.1, array([2, 3, 4, 5, 6])]], dtype=object)
```

Print is similar.  `reshape`, `concatenate`, `ravel` etc don't join the floats and array.

Instead lets make an array to hold the expected values, and copy them to it:

```
In [44]: B=np.zeros((3,9),float)
In [45]: B[:,:4]=A[:,:4]
```

Copying the float columns is easy.  But reworking the arrays into something that can be copied as a block, requires concatenation.  The `vstack` form seems to do the trick:

```
In [46]: B[:,4:]=np.vstack(A[:,-1])
In [47]: B
Out[47]: 
array([[ 0. ,  0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0. ,  1. ,  2. ,  3. ,  4. ],
       [ 0.4,  0.5,  0.6,  0.7,  1. ,  2. ,  3. ,  4. ,  5. ],
       [ 0.8,  0.9,  1. ,  1.1,  2. ,  3. ,  4. ,  5. ,  6. ]])
```

I had to recreate your array, based on what I know of array displays, including the object type.  Then I just had to play around, trying various ways of joining the values.  So there was a lot of trial and error.